# Can Apple Push Notifications be used as message queues?

Tags: ios, sockets, apple-push-notifications, chat

Lets say I have a chat application and I am messaging another user (User B), our messages are being received normally using sockets, however when the User B goes offline he is disconnected from the socket server however user A is continues to text him so my server issues a push notification to User B's device for every message User A sends. My question is will APNS act as a message broker and queue all the messages until User B logs back in and receives them? Or do I have to store unreceived messages elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is readily found in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1)

> Apple Push Notification service includes a Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts to deliver a notification and the destination device is offline, APNs stores the notification for a limited period of time and delivers it when the device becomes available again. This component stores only the most recent notification per device and per app. If a device is offline, sending a notification request targeting that device causes the previous request to be discarded. If a device remains offline for a long time, all its stored notifications in APNs are discarded.

So, no, you can't use APN as a message broker.

You can use the push notification as a signal to wake up and sync with a server-side message queue. RabbitMQ or Kafka might be candidate brokers, and MQTT looks promising as a protocol.   You will need to work out how and when you discard the contents of message queues that are not successfully delivered to a device.

Comment: Is storing unreceived messages in RabbitMq a better approach than just putting them in a database and then selecting them once the user logs back in?

Comment: @RyanMurphy: Rather depends on scale. The approach with a database is harder to scale than a message queue.  Message queues tend to have well defined semantics about 'consuming' messages - if you make a request to a server, which subsequently gets the messages from the db, what happens if the mobile device doesn't receive the reply?   You'll need to build some kind of acknowledgement that the device actually got them before removing them.  In essence you're building a concurrent MSG Q out of a database - and it's not actually that easy.